# How to boot a Surface Pro 3 off a USB Drive

Tags: boot, usb, windows-10-preview, microsoft-surface-pro

I have a Surface Pro 3 with Windows 8.1 installed upon it. I'm trying to set it up to Dual-Boot to the Windows 10 Technial P following some instructions I found on [Windows Central](http://www.windowscentral.com/how-dual-boot-windows-10-preview-windows-81).

I have downloaded the Windows 10 x64 iso.
I have downloaded the Windows USB/DVD Download Tool and put the iso onto my USB memory stick.
I have rebooted into the UEFI settings and changed the boot order to usb->ssd.
Then I rebooted and expected to boot into the Windows 10 installer. Instead it just booted into the Windows 8.1 login screen.

I have tried disabling Secure Boot which made no difference. 
I have tried rebooting using windows 8 settings update and recovery to get into the recovery menu and then selecting to boot from the USB drive and still no joy.
I can open the USB drive in Windows 8.1 and see that it has the setup files upon it.

Is it possible that there is something about my USB stick that is preventing it being used as a boot drive? I'd like to know before shelling out on a new one.

Comment: @Kris - You shouldn't have to disable fast boot in order to boot to a EFI enabled boot disk, provided the boot order was changed, and UEFI firmware settings were changed by booting to it by using the menu.

Comment: @MartinBrown - Why don't you just launch the Windows 10 installer from within Windows?

Comment: The Windows USB/DVD Download Tool has its limitations so I recommend you turn Secure Boot back on, then use Rufus to create the UEFI-enabled USB installer. See if that boots properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the issue was that UEFI computers don't like booting off NTFS formatted USB sticks.

I recreated the disk as a FAT32 disk by running a command prompt with Administrator privileges and the typing:

```
C:\>diskpart.exe
DISKPART>list disk
DISKPART>select disk 2 /* where 2 is the number of the disk to use from the list */
DISKPART>clean
DISKPART>create partition primary
DISKPART>active
DISKPART>format fs=fat32 /* it is important not to use NTFS here */
DISKPART>assign
DISKPART>exit
```

This left my memory stick mounted as drive D:. I then mounted the Windows 10 .iso file as drive G:, this facility is built into windows 8+.

Then I used the following:

```
C:\>G:
G:\>cd boot
G:\>bootsect.exe /nt60 d:
G:\>xcopy G:\*.* D:\ /E /H /F
```

Finally I rebooted the computer and it booted strait off the USB stick.